# Replace Enclosed Alphanumerics in Python

Tags: python, string, unicode, ascii

How can I replace characters such as , ①,Ⓐ to their 'normal' forms in python?

Note, however, I would still like accent character to remain the same (ç,á etc)

Hoping I don't need to make a dictionary.

More examples:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enclosed_Alphanumerics

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enclosed_Alphanumeric_Supplement

http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_circled_numbers.html

-=-=EDIT=--=-

For future people I used this, thanks AKX

```
(
         "".join(
             re.sub(r'([^\w])', '', unidecode.unidecode(ch)) #return only the word characters from the decode
                 if 
                         ord(ch) > 65535  #Emoticons
                     or (ord(ch) >= 9312 and ord(ch) <= 9472)       #circled
                     or (ord(ch) >= 65296 and ord(ch) <= 65305)     #latin numbers
                     or (ord(ch) >= 65313 and ord(ch) <= 65338)     #latin upper
                     or (ord(ch) >= 65345 and ord(ch) <= 9472)      #latin lower
                 else 
                     ch 
                 for ch in criteria
                   )
              )
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Inaccurate duplicate – OP needs to keep _some_ special characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no universal way, but happily someone else has made the dictionary for you: the [`unidecode`](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/) library works for your particular characters.

```
$ pip install unidecode
Successfully installed unidecode-1.3.4
$ python3
>>> import unidecode
>>> unidecode.unidecode(', ①,Ⓐ')
'[A], 1,A'
>>>
```

Unidecode will, however, also deburr accented characters, so you'll need a bit more to keep them.

For example, assuming all the strange characters are not in the Unicode basic plane, you can filter the string character by character:

```
>>> "".join(unidecode.unidecode(ch) if ord(ch) > 65535 else ch for ch in ' Oh lá lá')
'[A] Oh lá lá'
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. 
It doesn't work for numbers (⑥) and some letters (⒜) but hopefully this can be optimised with the character `ord` filter. 

If this site is accurate then I just need to include a few more ranges i.e. 'Circled numbers'
https://www.alansofficespace.com/unicode/unicd9399.htm